# How do I manipulate an element I just added with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a screen that loads a new template **using jQuery's `.load()`** when the user clicks a button, to provide with more options, a transition. This happens on the fly and it implies adding new HTML to the page, which is not there when the script happens to be loaded:

```js
(function($) {
  $('.go').on("click", function() {

    /* Poor man's reactivity. */
    var shouldReact = false;

    try {
      $('.top-part').animate({
        opacity: 0,
      }, {
        step: function() {
          $(this).css('transform', 'translate3d(0,-20px,0)');
        },
        duration: 'slow'
      }, 'swing');

      $('.go').animate({
        opacity: 1,
      }, {
        step: function() {
          $(this).css({
            'height': '100%',
            'width': '100%',
            'margin-top': '0',
            'z-index': '0',
            'background-color': '#0cff9b'
          });
        },
        duration: 1500
      }, 'swing');

      $('.go-text').animate({
        opacity: 0,
      }, {
        step: function() {
          $(this).css('transition', 'all 1s ease-out');
        }
      });
      shouldReact = true;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      shouldReact = false;
    }
    if (shouldReact == true) {
      $(this).css({
        'cursor': 'initial'
      });
      $(this).unbind("click");
      $(this).one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
        function(event) {
          $('.welcome_screen').css({
            'background-color': '#0cff9b'
          });
          $('.bottom-part').remove();
          render_screen__first_basic_settings();
        });
    } else {
      console.log("Stop! No need to react.");
    }
  });

  function genesis(screen_name, screen_selector, screen_contents, the_old) {
    let handler = '.welcome_screen';
    $(handler).prepend(screen_name);
    $(screen_selector).load(ABSPATH + screen_contents);
    $(the_old).remove();
  }

  /* Parts */
  function render_screen__first_basic_settings() {
    /*
    Each render of a screen must have a genesis, the template which it builds from and a
    cleanse / kill. We remove the old, to make space for the new.
    */

    genesis('<div id="screen-1" style="z-index:2;"></div>',
      '#screen-1',
      '/js/setup_theme_templates/basic_settings.html',
      '.top-part');

    // This is where I should be able to access the template, but I can't.
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* Welcome Screen & Setup Experience */

.welcome_screen {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@keyframes fadeInFromBottom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInFromTop {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes marginAdd {
  from {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-bottom: 48px;
  }
}

.welcome_screen .top-part {
  will-change: margin;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: margin 0.5s ease, transform 0.35s ease;
  animation: 0.8s ease 0s marginAdd;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.welcome_screen .bottom-part {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.welcome_screen .welcome-text {
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 72px;
  animation: 1s ease 0s 1 fadeInFromTop;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.welcome_screen .more-text {
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 72px;
  animation: 1s ease 0s 1 fadeInFromBottom;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.welcome_screen .bottom-part {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: 1s ease 0s 1 fadeInFromBottom;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.welcome_screen .go {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 480px;
  background-color: #fdff60;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 220px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.welcome_screen .go .go-text {
  position: absolute;
}

.welcome_screen .go:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 420px;
  height: 620px;
}

.welcome_screen .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#screen .basic_title {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome_screen">
  <div class="top-part">
    <p class="welcome-text">Welcome!</p>
    <p class="more-text"> Shall we set this up?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-part">
    <div data-tilt data-tilt-speed="150" data-tilt-reset="false" data-tilt-max="10" data-tilt-perspective="250" class="go">
      <p class="go-text">Let's Do It!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The template I'm loading is:

```
<div id="basic-settings-template">
    <style type="text/css">
    @keyframes fadeInFromBottom {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translate3d(0,10px,0);
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        }
    }

    #basic-settings-template {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        animation: 1s ease 0s 1 fadeInFromBottom;
    }

    .title-box {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .title-box .small-title {
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .title-box .big-cta {
        font-size: 60px;
        color: #1f1f1f;
        margin-bottom: 48px;
    }

    .blog-name input {
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-weight: 700;
        width: 480px;
        height: 48px;
        padding: 24px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        border: none;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
    }
    .blog-name input:focus {
        outline: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 136px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 136px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 136px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    </style>
    <div class="title-box">
        <p class="small-title">The Beginnings</p>
        <h3 class="big-cta">What should we call your blog?</h3>
    </div>
    <form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="blog-name">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Enter the name..." tabindex="1">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, trying to query `$('#basic-settings-template')` returns nothing, I believe this is because the script is running at the wrong time, but then it wouldn't explain why it would let me add the template itself, if the DOM is already finished packing.

How could I make this work and be able to work with the newly added HTML?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp you can use .on which is a replacement of delegate and it can operate on newly added code inserted in page using scripts.

Comment: @GurmeetSingh I was looking exactly for that. A way to say "hey, let's work with some virtual code!". Can you please suggest an answer with a real application of my code? Thank you. I'll be trying on my own meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) accepts a function as a parameter, function that will be run after the request completes.

Which means that you could do something like this:

```
$(screen_selector).load(ABSPATH + screen_contents, function(){
    // #basic-settings-template was added to the DOM, you can manipulate it now.
    $('#basic-settings-template').....
});
```

Comment: Beautiful! Any chance to port this into a non-anonymous function?

Comment: @JonathanGuerin Sure, just define a function and pass it's name as a parameter to the `load` function.

Comment: For some reason just passing the function name, in any conceivable form or name just doesn't work. What I want it to do is: `$('#basic-settings-template').remove();` but it only works from within an anonymous function.

Comment: @JonathanGuerin There is no difference between passing a function name or an anonymous function as a parameter. Make sure the function is in scope and you're passing it as a parameter correctly. (eg: `$(..).load(..., functionName)` instead of `$(...).load(..., functionName())`).

Comment: Sorry to bother. I did just that, as common-sense demands, but when I call it within `genesis`, no matter what I pass as the "callback" parameter, it doesn't work. Here's my full code: https://pastebin.com/YK8m7yaS

Comment: @JonathanGuerin it should be `genesis(......, test1)` instead of `genesis(......, 'test1')` (no quotes). `'test1'` is a string, `test1` is a reference to a function, very different things.

Comment: Thank you! Let's pretend this never happened, though, a bit ashamed :P